# CouchDB "[Circular]" when writing to an array

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-futon

In CouchDB, I am writing to an array and keep getting the message "[Circular]".  I am using Node.js to create the data to be written like this.

Say I have an two email objects in the same document in CouchDB:

```
unverifiedEmail = [{"address":"john@example.com","dateAdded":"1389215329484"}]
verifiedEmail = []
```

Now in Node.js I do this before writing.

```
var oldData = readFromCouchDb();
var newData = oldData;
newData.verifiedEmail.unshift(newData.unverifiedEmail[0]);
writeToCouchDb(newData);
```

Then when I view the document in Futon I see this:

```
unverifiedEmail = [{"address":"john@example.com","dateAdded":"1389215329484"}]
verifiedEmail = "[Circular]"
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue has to do with the depth of the way to set Javascript objects equal to each other.

To solve this, I used the following code in place of the unshift above:

```
newData.verifiedEmail.unshift(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newData.unverifiedEmail[0])));
```